# Appengine - Possible to get an entity using only key string without model name?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to be able to have a view that will act upon a number of different types of objects

all the view will get is the key string eg:

agpwb2xsdGhyZWFkchULEg9wb2xsY29yZV9hbnN3ZXIYAww

without knowing the model type, is it possible to retrieve the entity from just that key string?

thanks

Comment: What is the use case for this?  How can you have an object id without a model?

Answer (score 11):

No superclassing required, just use db.get():

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
key_str = 'agpwb2xsdGhyZWFkchULEg9wb2xsY29yZV9hbnN3ZXIYAww'
entity = db.get(key_str)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you design your models so they all use a common superclass it should be possible to retrieve your objects by using something like:

```
entity = CommonSuperclass.get('agpwb2xsdGhyZWFkchULEg9wb2xsY29yZV9hbnN3ZXIYAww')
```