# GAE - access model metadata

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

From [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/918507/1177441), I gather I can fetch a record from my db without even knowing its model, I just require the key. If this works, how do I then access the model metadata so that I can find out its kind?

**Update - from the answer provided**

```
record_kind = record.kind()
#talk about being intuitive..... and thick
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kind is specified in the key, see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass#Introduction